# Loading functions automatically?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, structure

I have a class that defines new meta boxes in an admin area of a web site. Each new box requires quite a lot of arguments, so the defining of each new object is kept in a separate function.

```
function my_metabox(){
   $args = array(/*the args*/);
   $metabox = new MetaBox($args);
}
```

And then I have a function, positioned where I need the boxes loaded, to load all of the metaboxes at once.

```
function load_metaboxes(){
  my_metabox();
  my_other_boxes();
  etc_etc();
}
```

The problem mostly is having to manually alert the `load_metaboxes()` function whenever I create a new box, is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
//declaring my functions
function test_funct_1() { echo 'test'; return true; }
function test_funct_2() { return true; }
function test_funct_3() { return true; }
function test_funct_4() { return true; }

//get all function declared
$func = get_defined_functions();
//show only functions declared by user (you)
print_r($func['user']);

//call a individual function
$func['user'][0]();
```

Comment: this would load all my other functions, and still require me to manually check the right functions were being invoked. In fact, it's more work.

Comment: you can verify by function name if is the correct set of functions, to do it you just need renamed your functions to pass a prefix name (eg. meta_metabox1(), meta_metabox2()), and loop into $func['user'] array to verify if the name starts with "meta", if true you can call this function, else continue.

Answer (score -1):

use php autload magin method

here is the documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

in your class create a method name __autoload and call all the function in it so when you make an instance of the class the function called in __autoload will automatically loaded

Comment: This is not how __autoload is used, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.